# Parsing a date string to get the year

Tags: c#, date

I have a string variable that stores a date like "05/11/2010".

How can I parse the string to get only the year?

So I will have another year variable like `year = 2010`.

Answer (score 27):

You can use the [DateTime.Parse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) to parse the string to a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) value which has a [Year Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.year.aspx):

```
var result = DateTime.Parse("05/11/2010").Year;
// result == 2010
```

Depending on the culture settings of the operating system, you may need to provide a [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx):

```
var result = DateTime.Parse("05/11/2010", new CultureInfo("en-US")).Year;
// result == 2010
```

Answer (score 14):

This should work for you.

```
string myDate = "05/11/2010"; 
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(myDate);
int year = date.Year;
```

Comment: Sorry, but such a constructor of `DateTime` class does not exist.

Comment: @Serge You appear to be right. Thats what I get for trying to think so late and not confirming before posting. :P

Comment: I'd avoid parsing without specifying a culture.

Answer (score 4):

If the date string format is fixed (dd/MM/yyyy), I would like to recommend you using [DateTime.ParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

The code:

```
const string dateString = "12/02/2012";
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
// Use the invariant culture for the provider parameter,
// because of custom format pattern.
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", provider);
Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
```

Also I think it might be a little bit faster than [DateTime.Parse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx), because the Parse method tries parsing several representations of date-time string.

Answer (score 4):

you could also used **Regex** to get the **year** in the string "05/11/2010"

```
public string getYear(string str)
{
    return (string)Regex.Match(str, @"\d{4}").Value;
}

var result = getYear("05/11/2010");

2010
```

Comment: This also matches the first 4 digits of my phone number, and for some reason returns the year as a string.

Comment: definitely, but if the question only in date format it would works.

Answer (score 3):

Variant of dtb that I use:

```
string Year = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString()).Year.ToString();
```