# Extract some text from a text

Tags: c#, datetime, extract

I have a Date with string format (For example 01/01/2013).
How to I get the year (2013)?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [parsing a date string to get the year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246466/parsing-a-date-string-to-get-the-year)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about parsing it to a `DateTime`?

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2013");
var year = date.Year;
```

If you have other/special formatting, you can take a look at [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You may parse string via `DateTime.ParseExact` method.

```
string strDate="01/01/2013";
string format="MM/dd/yyyy";
DateTime date=DateTime.ParseExact(strDate,
                                  format,
                                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
int year=date.Year;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sting.Substing() method

```
string s = "01/01/2013";
string year = s.Substring(6,4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code below
"
String s = "01/01/2013";

Datetime date= Datetime.parse(s);

date.Year;

"

Answer (score 0):

You could parse your string to get a `DateTime` object, then get the year:

```
string test = "01/01/2013";
DateTime theDate = DateTime.ParseExact(test, "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
int theYear = theDate.Year;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to parse the string to Date. Then pick the Year from the date.
Example:

```
string s = "01/01/2013";
var date = DateTime.Parse(s);
var year = date.Year;
```

DateTime can be found in the System namespace.