# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime12

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

here I bind date (from table) in drop down list in this format 2015, and want to populate data in grid view when the date in grid view equal to selected value in drop down list. Error says "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime". Error in this line

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventDate", DateTime.Parse(ddlLocation.SelectedValue));
```

This is the drop down list code

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DATEPART(yyyy, eventDate) AS eventDate FROM events group by eventDate", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        ddlLocation.DataSource = dt;
        ddlLocation.DataTextField = "eventDate";
       ddlLocation.DataValueField = "eventDate";
        ddlLocation.DataBind();
        ddlLocation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("All", ""));
```

and this is grid view code:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id, eventDate, eventName from events where eventDate = @eventDate", con);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventDate", DateTime.Parse(ddlLocation.SelectedValue));
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     da.Fill(dt);
     }
     else
     {
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id, eventDate, eventName from events", con);
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     da.Fill(dt);
     }
      con.Close();
     gvDetails.DataSource = dt;
     gvDetails.DataBind();
   }
```

Comment: What is the value of ddlLocation.SelectedValue? Knowing that it should be obvious.

Comment: the value of ddlLocation.SelectedValue is 2015. User can select any date in this format 2010

Comment: @Algiri just "2015"? [You'll need more than that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If it's just a year why store it as a `DateTime` at all?

Comment: I need to store it as Date Time because I need it for other purpose

Comment: @Algiri well as Adam and I have pointed out, you'll need more than just the year. *"I need it for other purposes"* -  do you need it for other purposes in the database, or in the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Adam has answered the question, allow me to explain how you can use this in your code:

As Adam has explained - your input `ddlLocation.SelectedValue` is not in the correct format. What you need to do is first set that value to a full date. What you can try instead is this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventDate", DateTime.Parse("1/1/" + ddlLocation.SelectedValue));
```

By adding `"1/1/"` to your value, this will make your `ddlLocation.SelectedValue = "1/1/2015"` which is a *valid* input for the `DateTime.Parse` method.

Later, when you need to access this date, you can then use Adam's suggestion of

```
var result = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015").Year;
//result = 15
```

Comment: i did this changes but still does not work. as you can see drop down list sends date like 2015, but when I want to access it in grid view code it does not work  here `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventDate", DateTime.Parse("1/1/" + ddlLocation.SelectedValue));`

Comment: try `DateTime.Parse("1/1/" + (ddlLocation.SelectedValue).ToString));` or `DateTime.Parse("1/1/" + Convert.ToString(ddlLocation.SelectedValue));`

Comment: @Algiri let me know how that goes

Answer (score 2):

A `DateTime` stores a complete value. You can't only store a year in a `DateTime` right away. You're better off storing the whole date and then parsing the year as a `string` or an `int`. Make the modifications on the back-end appropriately or cast it on the front end to only a string or int.

A solution around this would be on the front-end I guess with the following taken from the user, **dtb** from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246466/parsing-a-date-string-to-get-the-year)

```
var result = DateTime.Parse("05/11/2010").Year;
//result = 10
```

Comment: could you show me how to apply this answer in the current code?

Comment: @Algiri the problem is that your input is not in the correct format. You *need* the full date to parse it correctly. To get the year, you still need the month and day (even if those are always `1/1/(whatever year)`)

Comment: where do I need to parse the full date?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

```
string Text="22/11/2009";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);              
Console.WriteLine("update date => "+date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```